# GenericWorkItem is not public in JobIntentService

Tags: android, androidx, intentservice

After migrating my code to AndroidX, I am getting this

***error :GenericWorkItem is not public in JobIntentService; cannot be accessed from outside package***

```
@Override
    GenericWorkItem dequeueWork() {
        try {
            return super.dequeueWork();
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            LogUtil.info(TAG, "ignored "+ex.getMessage());

        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my code block which is giving error.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this class is in the `android.support.v4.app` package.
To solve the problem, move this class to the `androidx.core.app` package.
Then `android.support.v4.app` package can be removed.